# Get "Bad Request" when using json api

Tags: json, grails

I am trying to get a json post working using grails, and keep getting "bad request". I have stripped down everything to the point that the routine doesn't make much sense, but it is simple.

The api should return an error text requesting valid parameters...

You will be able to guess that I am pretty new to this, so any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks...

```
def testit() {
    def statusLine = "200"
    def http = new HTTPBuilder( 'http://api.scribblepics.com' )

    def postBody = [
            'apiKey': 'test',
            'sender': [
                'firstName': 'First',
                'lastName': 'Last',
                'email': 'first.last@mail.com'
                ]
            ]

    http.post( path: '/postcard/create', body: postBody,
            requestContentType: URLENC ) { resp ->

        println "status: ${resp.statusLine}"
        statusLine = resp.statusLine
        assert resp.statusLine.statusCode == 200
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing other mandatory parameters `recipient`, `message`, `imageData`.

Or have you already tried with these and are still getting the same error?

Comment: oops. Yes, I just noticed that the return code is 400, even though it also returns the information about the missing parameters.

But if I use all parameters it also returns code 400. An example of the postbody follows, but for obvious reasons I can't post the apikey

Comment: def postBody = [
    'apiKey': 'test',
    'sender': [
     'firstName': 'Ft',
     'lastName': 'Lt',
     'email': 'f.l@mail.com'
                ],
                'recipient': [
                        'name': 'full',
                        'addressLine1': 'Main',
                        'addressLine2': 'Main2',
                        'city': 'city',
                        'state': 'st',
                        'zip': '12',
                        'country': 'cou'
                ],
                'message': 'Test',
                'imageUrl':'http://www.google.ch'
        ]

Answer (score 0):

```
        def postBody = [
            'apiKey': 'test',
            'sender': [
                'firstName': 'First',
                'lastName': 'Last',
                'email': 'first.last@mail.com'
            ],
            'recipient': [
                    'name': 'full name',
                    'addressLine1': 'Main Street',
                    'addressLine2': 'Main Street2',
                    'city': 'city',
                    'state': 'state',
                    'zip': '1234',
                    'country': 'country'
            ],
            'message': 'A test message...',
            'imageUrl':'http://www.google.ch/imgres?sa=X&biw=1680&bih=859&tbm=isch&tbnid=Dw_q5yUyBtrHAM%3A&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FFerrari_F430&docid=sKowXM25Yu8uoM&imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2F1%2F17%2FFerrari_F430_front_20080605.jpg&w=2275&h=1160&ei=jsAJU9CHL6OK5AS7u4GQAw&zoom=1&ved=0CGUQhBwwAA&iact=rc&dur=2130&page=1&start=0&ndsp=18'
    ]
```